# I have a UItableView cell with a Image but can't get a image click to allow parameters

Tags: swift, uitableview, parameters, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a **EDIT2** *UItableView*, in Swift, with the normal labels and relevant Information. I have added a Image to the cell and all is working except when I click on the image I would like to open another ViewController with that particular cells relevant information. I have used:

```
     let popup: UITapGestureRecognizer   = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.popupalrmcontrnt))
     cell.alrmwarning.addGestureRecognizer(popup);
```

as the means for calling the **pushViewController** function, But the Viewcontoller requires a parameter AlarmID to be set Beforehand. Said Viewcontroller needs AlarmID to fetch its relevant information.

**Edit1**  The parameter is dependant on the selected cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use UIButton. you can set image to the button as background image. Also you can pass  relevant  info as an object to the new ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Create a **closure** variable in cell:

```
class SomeCell: UITableViewCell {

    var imageClicked: (() -> Void)?

}
```

then in action of your tap gesture `self.popupalrmcontrnt`
add this line

```
func popupalrmcontrnt() {

    self.imageClicked?()
}
```

then in your **cellForRow**, you can access this as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    (cell as? SomeCell)?.imageClicked = {
           //Navigate to your view controller here
    }

    return cell
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I get out of scope errors... Tried all logical ways as well

Comment: It's a normal implementation of UItbleview with a UIImage with a tap gesture. The issue comes in when you Add "var imageCl...(()->void)?" to the cell. The cells scope is not allowing it to be accessed in cellForRow. And moving it to a global variable means the Var would have changed based on many Cells activating the code. The variable is dependant on the row selected.

Comment: @Poseidon Edited the answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: class SomeCell: UITableViewCell { Was in wrong class... all along ill check now. And edit this comment

Comment: class SomeCell: UITableViewCell { Was in wrong class... all along ill check now and edit:.@Agent Smith. the self.imageClicked?() code does not execute the" cell as? SomeCell)?.imageClicked  "part. It simply does nothing :(